# How can I load an npm library that uses window object in Remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix

Using Remix v 1.16.1, React and a simple project that loads a PDF and tries to print it.

The loading process is OK, it shows it and, in order to print it, I used a small library called `print-js`.

The problem (I suppose) is that library, when I run the code, uses `window.print()` (which only runs at browsers).

So, I placed some protection code in order to make it runs only at browsers:

```
const onPrintPrintJS = () => { 
    if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
      printJS({ printable: pdfData, type: 'pdf', base64: true })
    }
    
}
```

But I think the problem is not there as even when I comment out the code and refreshes the page, Remix complains with the following:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marcos/javascript_projects/printPdf/node_modules/print-js/dist/webpack:/printJS/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:2)
```

Is Remix imcompatible with libraries like that? Or there is a way to tell it that library is supposed to be run only at browsers?